# MATLAB (Image Processing)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I store multiple image in a loop for example: `image_1,image_2`. Where `1,2` are not fixed, they depend on the loop.

Comment: Can you choose a better title please? This question isn't about image processing.

Comment: Are you storing image data or image handles?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it like this then use the `eval` command.

```
eval(sprintf('image_%i = thisimage;', i))
```

But beware that `eval` considered harmful. You'd be better off with something like a cell array.

```
images{i} = thisimage;
```

Or, if they're just graphics handles, then use @sta 's suggestion to store in a regular array:

```
images(i) = imageHandle;
```

Answer (score 1):

The handles for figures/axes etc. should be floats that you can append to a vector. After the loop you can access the figure via this handle.